# Resolve connection timeout exception

Tags: java, spring-boot

Requirement:
The API should allow multiple files to be uploaded to the repository.

What have I done?
I am iterating the files using parallelstream, encoding the content, and sending it as a requestbody in the rest template. I am sending the files one by one.

Issue:
If I upload large files, like 7 MB, then it takes around 6 seconds to get a response from the external service. If I upload 4 files with a size of 7 MB, then it's taking around 30 seconds. Response timing is increasing as the number of files increases. If I increase the number of files to 6, then I am getting a connection timeout exception.

1. I want to know if anything can be done from my end to get the response faster.
2. How do I avoid this connection timeout exception?
3. Even though I am using parallelstream, why is response timing increasing when the number of files is increasing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue may happen because of bottleneck either on application or external service or network or limitation of resource.

- Asynchronous upload: you can use `ExecutorService` and `CompletableFuture` upload file Asynchronous without affecting main thread.
- You can increase your `RestTemplate` connection timeout.

```java
int time = 120;
// time is modify as your need
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplateBuilder()
                           .setConnectTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(time))
                           .setReadTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(time))
                           .build();
```